# Facebook Graph API getting user Interests after v2.3

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Does anyone know if there will be another way of accessing a user's interests? 
According to the link below it seems like they are only getting rid of it, without some kind of replacement.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog:
- Edges and Permissions - /v2.3/{user_id}/interests and /v2.3/{user_id}/activities edges as well as user_interests and user_activities permissions are deprecated in v2.3.

Comment: I am facing this issue. Looks like they are not giving any replacement for getting interests. let us know if you find out any other way.

Comment: Been researching for days and could not find anything.

Comment: It's a subset of user likes and you can just fetch the user/likes instead:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/likes